# Model item DateTime plus 2 Year

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a model like:

```
public string GroupName {get;set;}
public DateTime? AssignDate {get;set;}
```

I add this model to a View. For Model Item `AssignDate`, I want to add plus 2 years. So if the assigndate is 01/Jan/2019 then the View is 01/Jan/2021.

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssignDate)</td>
```

Does anyone have an idea for this thing?
Thank you.

Comment: Null check and `.AddYears(2)`?

Comment: @John, could you post it to the answer please? so i can check and accept the answer if it is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your DateTime object is [nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/) check if it is null first using `.HasValue` (a bool).

After than you can simply add years to the object with `.AddYears(int)`. Documentation on `AddYears` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addyears?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Remove the `@Html.DisplayFor` first

Comment: `<td>@item.AssignDate.Value.AddYears(2).ToString("yyy-MM-dd")</td>`

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:

So I remove `@Html.DisplayFor` and change to the following code:

```
<td>@item.AssignDate.Value.AddYears(2).ToString("yyy-MM-dd")</td>
```

Cheers,